# Why does ArrayList.add() add values to multiple arraylists in java when they are defined as a = b?

Tags: java, list

I have recently come across a weird 'feature' in java that means ArrayLists seem to magically have items added to them when I add items to a different list. See below:

```java
List<Integer> i = new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<Integer> i2 = i;
i.add(77);
System.out.println(i);
System.out.println(i2);
```

This program gives the output:

```
[77]
[77]
```

However, if you replace the lists with just integers:

```java
int i = 5;
int i2 = i;
i = 7;
System.out.println(i);
System.out.println(i2);
```

It works as I would expect giving the result

```
7
5
```

Why does this happen and how can I stop `i` and `i2` becoming the same list when I do `i.add()`?

Comment: They don't become the same list when you do `i.add()`, they were *always* the same list. There's no magic here; `i2 = i` **does not** create a copy.

Comment: To add more info, the correct way to make a copy would be `List<Integer> i2 = new ArrayList<>(i);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primitives like `int` behave differently from objects like `ArrayList` in this respect. Using `=` with a primitive will produce a duplicate of the primitive, whereas doing so with an object will give you *the same object*. If you then try to mutate the object (for example, `.add()`), then the object will be mutated, and both of the variables referencing it will be able to see that.

To make a 'soft copy' (a different list containing the same elements), you can call `ArrayList`'s constructor with an existing `ArrayList`:

```
List<Integer> i = new ArrayList<>();
List<Integer> i2 = new ArrayList<>(i);
```